# Hide inherited protected method

Tags: c#, inheritance, protected

Is it possible to hide or block a inherited `protected virtual` or `protected abstract` method so that further inheriting classes cannot access them?

For example:

```
class Base<T>
{
    protected abstract T CreateInstance();
}

class Derivative : Base<Derivative>
{
    protected sealed override Derivative CreateInstance()
    {
        return new Derivative();
    }
}

class MoreDerivative : Derivative
{
    public MoreDerivative()
    {
        // cannot access CreateInstance here
    }
}
```

I don’t think it is implemented in the language, but maybe there is an annotation or something like that.

Comment: You could make `Derivative` a wrapper for `Base<T>` instead of inheriting from it (selecting what functionality to forward on to subclasses). It would break the inheritance chain (obviously), but any other method would be breaking that contract anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  When you define a member for a type, you're saying that that type and all of it's sub-types will have that member.  There is no way to "revoke" that.  This assumption is an integral part of the type system.

You probably want to consider using composition here, rather than inheritance.  Create a type that has a field of type `Derivative`, rather than inheriting from it.

Comment: Since `protected` methods are only visible by deriving classes and when deriving a class you need to explicitly give the base class’ name, why shouldn’t it be possible to customize the protected method availability for further deriving classes? I think Liskov’s substitution principle is not useful in that case because no replacement of the base is possible. The requested construct could be used to inject functionality in the base class which should only be invoked by the base class or the defining class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish something along the spirit of what you're intending using a delegate:

```
class Base<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _createInstance;

    public Base(Func<T> createInstance)
    {
        _createInstance = createInstance;
    }

    private T CreateInstance()
    {
        return _createInstance();
    }
}

class Derivative : Base<Derivative>
{
    public Derivative() : base(CreateInstance)
    {

    }

    private static Derivative CreateInstance()
    {
        return new Derivative();
    }
}

class MoreDerivative : Derivative
{
    public MoreDerivative()
    {
        // cannot access CreateInstance here
    }
}
```

---

Non-static implementation:

```
class Base<T>
{
    private readonly Func<Base<T>, T> _createInstance;

    public Base(Func<Base<T>, T> createInstance)
    {
        _createInstance = createInstance;
    }

    private T CreateInstance()
    {
        return _createInstance(this);
    }
}

class Derivative : Base<Derivative>
{
    public Derivative() : base(CreateInstance)
    {

    }

    private static Derivative CreateInstance(Base<Derivative> caller)
    {
        return ((Derivative)caller).CreateInstance();
    }

    private Derivative CreateInstance()
    {
        return new Derivative();
    }
}

class MoreDerivative : Derivative
{
    public MoreDerivative()
    {
        // cannot access CreateInstance here
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never using `CreateInstance` in the base class.  You might as well just remove it.

Comment: @Dan True that’s sufficient in certain scenarios but `CreateInstance` is `static` here, that was not the question.

Comment: @Servy, I mainly included it for rough compatibility with the OP's signature (how he might have been calling it from within Base), but yeah, you could just use the delegate directly from within the implementation of Base.

Comment: @ominug, it can be made non-static by using `Func<Base<T>, T>` instead, if necessary, passing in 'this' from Base and having the Derived implementation cast the parameter appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who ends up here, you could also make an internal virtual method, as long as the only classes you want to see the method are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. To stick to your example, `MoreDerivative` is still a subtype of `Base<Derivative>`, and `Base<>` contains the `CreateInstance` method. So you *have to* have access to the method. And if you didn’t, you could just cast the object to its base type and access it then.

Comment: Explicit interface implementations allow for code like this, if `A` is an interface instead of a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `Obsolete` annotation to `Derivative.CreateInstance` leads to a compiler warning when trying to invoke the method in `MoreDerivative`. The `EditorBrowsable` hides the method in IntelliSense if the invocation is not in the same solution as the declaration.

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Obsolete("Method must only be invoked by the base class.", true)]
protected sealed override Derivative CreateInstance() { /*...*/ }
```